# How to create third person camera with lock on ability. Similar to Rocket League - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I currently have a camera setup with the camera being the child of the car so that the camera is a constantly moving with the car. I have the ball set as the target and the camera is locked onto the ball using `transform.LookAt(target.transform);`. However, when the car turns, it leaves the cameras sight and the camera continues to look at the target object. An example of the problem I'm having can be found here:

[image]

And here:

[image]

The camera moves in between the car and the target object, but I need some sort of rotation to keep the car between the camera and the target object. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Put the camera in an empty object, with the center of that object parented to the car. The rotate the big empty object, rather than the camera. There are better ways, but you will need to do some maths.

Comment: @Catwood I put the empty object as a child of the car, then I have the camera as the child of the empty object. But how would I rotate the empty object?

Comment: Same way you were rotating the camera?

Comment: @Catwood I did the steps you mentioned above and it didn't solve my problem. I need the camera to rotate around the car in order to keep the car in the picture while the camera follows the target object. I may have done something wrong, because I also don't know how to "rotate the big empty object". How can I rotate it?

Comment: You can still use the `transform.LookAt(target.transform);` but attach it to the empty game object.  The camera should be a child of the game object and you can adjust the local position of the camera to suit your needs. The parent empty game object then needs to be positioned where you car is. It will take some tweaking, but it will work.

Comment: All this can be achieved instead with maths and Vectors in a script and I would suggest doing this as it will be a great exercise that will give you some knowledge that will be useful time and time again while using Unity.

Comment: Great, I got it! Thanks a lot!